# How do I fix error NameError: name 'questions_test' is not defined on a basic multiple choice quiz program

Tags: python

I am trying to make an extremely basic multiple-choice quiz. I made two python files. One to define a class for the questions, and then the other to have the questions and run the quiz.

File to make a class for the questions

```
 class Question_class:
        def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
            self.prompt = prompt
            self.answer = answer
```

File with everything else

```
from Question_File import Question_class

question_prompts =[
    "What color are apples?\n(a) Red/Green\n(b)Purple\n(c) Pink\n\n",
    "What color are kiwis on the inside?\n(a) Purple\n(b) Green\n(c) Yellow\n\n",
    "What color are oranges?\n(a) Orange\n(b) Yellow\n(c) Blue\n\n"
]

questions_class_objects = [
    Question_class(question_prompts[0], "a"),
    Question_class(question_prompts[1], "b"),
    Question_class(question_prompts[2], "a"),
]
def run_test(questions_test):
    score=0
    for question in questions_class_objects:
        answer= input(question_prompts.prompt)
        if answer == question_prompts.answer:
            score += 1
    print("You got "+ str(score)+ " out of " + str(len(questions_class_objects)) + " correct")
run_test(questions_test)
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/clubj/PycharmProjects/untitled9/Multiple Choice Quiz.py", line 25, in <module>
    run_test(questions_test)
NameError: name 'questions_test' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I recently started learning python, so I suppose I made a stupid mistake. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The variable `questions_test` doesn't exist. I think you want to change `def run_test(questions_test)` to `def run_test()` without any parameters.

Comment: `questions_test` is not defined anywhere and you are not using it in your function anyway. Remove the parameter from your function and from the call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `questions_test` doesn't exist and, based on your `run_test` function, is not required anyway. Therefore, you may remove the function parameter and pass no arguments when you call `run_test`, i.e.:

```
def run_test():
    score=0
    for question in questions_class_objects:
        answer= input(question.prompt)
        if answer == question.answer:
            score += 1
    print("You got "+ str(score)+ " out of " + str(len(questions_class_objects)) + " correct")

run_test()
```

Comment: After changing the program to that, the error now changes to  
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/clubj/PycharmProjects/untitled9/Multiple Choice Quiz.py", line 22, in 
    <module>
        run_test()
      File "C:/Users/clubj/PycharmProjects/untitled9/Multiple Choice Quiz.py", line 17, in 
    run_test
        answer= input(question_prompts.prompt)
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'prompt'

    Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: I have fixed your code in my answer; you were still referring to the list of `Question_class` objects, rather than the current instance `question`.